# Users with display name format "user\d+"

Tags: support

I frequently see users across all communities with a display name of "user" followed by a bunch of numbers, or in terms of a regex, `user\d+`. This doesn't seem like an elaborate username choice, so what's going on?

Comment: Users are free to choose almost any nick they want, including to keep their auto generated one. So what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, all usernames start off as userxxxxxx where x is a series of numbers (the internal user ID on Stack Exchange's database), so this is really common.

When someone first decides on their user name, it can be very easy to just replace the numbers with something, so this is quite common.

As to why regex - who knows. It's not that surprising when you think that Stack Exchange attracts technical folks...

Comment: I completely forgot about that when I created my account...thanks, this makes more sense now.

Comment: "x" is not just a random number, it's the internal user ID in the database. It's sequential. (So the first part of the answer is bit misleading)

Comment: Have I suggested it was random? I'll add extra words to clarify.

Comment: @sha Betterererer?

Comment: Yeah, it was implied that it's random. Better now. Cheers! :-)